# How to fake a keyboard shift press. Qt, Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, qt, point-cloud-library

I develop some software for a touch based tablet PC. The unit has no keyboard and has only a touch screen (the touch screen emulates a mouse). The OS is Windows 10 and we are using Qt as the graphical user interface framework.

We rely on a class library Point Cloud Library that has a component that requires the SHIFT key to be pressed to make something happen when we do a left mouse click.

I need to make the underlying software component believe that the SHIFT key has been pressed.

I have tried to send keypress events to the Qt widget via "Qt means" but the fake SHIFT keypress doesn't seem to reach the underlying sw. component. Probably  since it is in a unrelated class library to Qt and that this software class library probably checks key events differently (for example via OS calls, c++ std ways or similar).

This didn't seem to work when trying the "Qt way":

```
QKeyEvent key_press(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Shift, Qt::ShiftModifier);
QApplication::sendEvent(ui->qvtkWidget, &key_press);
```

Therefore I probably need to use an operating system method to fake a SHIFT key press.

Question: 
How can I can do an OS system call or similar from Qt to make the underlying software component think that a SHIFT key has been pressed and held ( at the same time the user presses the left mouse button).

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/simulating-a-keystroke-in-win32-c-or-c-using-sendinput/

Comment: Strong indications, that this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please explain, what the Point Cloud Library does exactly, when you shift-click (and where). If all else fails, have you tried sending a [QMouseEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html) instead? It allows you to send keyboard modifiers along with the click. Depending on how the library determines, whether the [Shift] key is held down, you might be out of luck, though. Particularly when used with Qt, sporting a mind-numbingly broken message handling implementation.

Comment: Since I doubt a depressed shift key is your actual goal, but rather just a means to an end, a more graceful approach would be to directly tell the underlying software component to change its behavior to (whatever behavior it has when the shift key is depressed).   This might require modifications to the underlying software component, of course, and if that's not possible then you might be left with hacks (like faking the press of a shift key) as your only option, but it's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not to fake a shift key input but disable the shift checking at interaction level. Definitely an XY problem.

The vtk InteractorStyle classes are responsible for handling user input events. You can see that in [line 506](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/visualization/src/pcl_visualizer.cpp#L506) of pcl_visualizer.cpp

```
boost::signals2::connection
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::registerPointPickingCallback (boost::function<void (const pcl::visualization::PointPickingEvent&)> callback)
{
  return (style_->registerPointPickingCallback (callback));
}
```

the callback gets registered in a `PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle` class.

You can pass your own custom interactor style at construction of `PCLVisualizer` so this one you can override safely. The constructor to use is this [one](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#ab1d7dcec36942a12fa15dbc2a42c0eb4)

```
PCLVisualizer (int &argc, char **argv, const std::string &name="", PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle *style=PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle::New(), const bool create_interactor=true)
```

The `PointPickingCallback` class is being [added automatically](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/visualization/src/interactor_style.cpp#L116) as a mouse callback upon initializing the default interactor style. So in order to override this behavior, you're required to derive your own class from `PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle` and override the `Initialize()` method and pass this new interactor style to a `PCLVisualizer` upon construction.

The [Execute](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/visualization/src/point_picking_event.cpp#L64) method inside the `PointPickingCallback` is where the check for the shift key happens.

```
void
pcl::visualization::PointPickingCallback::Execute (vtkObject *caller, unsigned long eventid, void*)
{
  PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle *style = reinterpret_cast<PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle*>(caller);
  vtkRenderWindowInteractor* iren = reinterpret_cast<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle*>(caller)->GetInteractor ();
  if (style->CurrentMode == 0)
  {
    if ((eventid == vtkCommand::LeftButtonPressEvent) && (iren->GetShiftKey () > 0))
    {
      float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
      int idx = performSinglePick (iren, x, y, z);
      // Create a PointPickingEvent if a point was selected   
      [... and so on]
```

In summary you're gonna need to:

1. Derive from `PointPickingCallback` a new class which overrides the check for the shift key inside the `Execute` method.
2. Derive from `PCLVisualizerInteractorStyle` and override the `Initialize` method to register your new custom `PointPickingCallback` class which doesn't check for the shift key, as a mouse callback.
3. Pass the new interactor style to the `PCLVisualizer`.

Worth noting. The visualizer supports two selection modes: rubber band for area selection and single point picking, which can be interchanged by pressing the key 'x'. I think the default one to be selected is the rubber band and that's why it might be checking for that shift key being pressed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the other solution is correct but I found an easier one.

Use the visualizers `setupInteractor()` function and give it the interactor of the `QVTKWidget` via : `QVTKWidget::interactor()->GetInteractorStyle()->GetInteractor()`

This should work when you press <kbd>shift</kbd>.